# computation of Hankel matrix for large data series

Tags: matlab, matrix, svd

i would like to conduct research in the following  topic :

i am frequently using  following matrix in  my research part
[image]

i have  wrote following code

```
Function [x ]=create_matrix1(b,l)
%This Function is used to Create Hankel Type Data Matrix
%x is a given data
%l represent window size
    n = length(b);
    m = n-l+1;
    x = zeros(m,l);
    for i=1:m
        x(i,:)=b(i:i+l-1);
    end;
```

for time series  with small amount of data is works  correctly, but for large  time series,  memory crushes, for instance, let us take real data from yahoo finance historical prices 
[image]

length of time series is equal to

```
>> length(BMW)

ans =

   257
```

for such  matrix, method works correctly

```
>> X=create_matrix(BMW,50);
```

size of X is equal

```
>> size(X)

ans =

   208    50
```

now let us consider following data
load quakevibration.mat

which generates data with sample size of 10000, in this program will crush, my finally goal is to  estimate SVD of given  matrix, matrix is created but i need approximation of  SVD,  which method is useful for this?and in general for large time series, how can i  process?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you are seeking about the **truncated or reduced SVD** method which is introduced [here](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/low-rank-approximations-1.html), for example.

This method is implemented in Matlab which is called [Fast SVD](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47132-fast-svd-and-pca), and approximate the SVD in a high efficiency.

Also, in case of limited memory you can use online algorithms such as [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179539/144441).

Comment: by the way, i am using matlab 2017a and program runs correctly, maybe  latest version of matlab  is using  some special  library for speed up program?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Yes, it is possible. As we don't know the exact implementation of codes behind, this improvement can be happened in the latest version. By the way, you can follow some existed benchmarks to find this.

Comment: but  when we dont have  enough memory? for instance we are trying to analyze data with size 500000  , then is it possible to create SVD ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili in case of limited memory you can use online algorithms such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179539/144441

Comment: thanks my friend, my first question is  about matrix itself, creation of matrix with dimension exceeded memory , how can i compute SVD of matrix from raw  time series without creation of actual matrix itself?